# readme in staticdocs

Tags: r

[staticdocs](https://github.com/hadley/staticdocs/) is a Hadley Wickham package that can make nifty web pages for a package.  I've [used it](http://trinker.github.com/qdap/) with great success (though haven't figured out how to add the examples without error yet) but each time I have to manually reformat the readme portion of the `index.html` file that is created.  This seems silly as it appears from the [ggplot2 staticdocs use](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/inst/staticdocs/index.r) that there is a way to set up readme in the index file inside of `inst/staticdocs/`.

Right now Hadley hasn't documented the package that well (staticdocs) and I'm unsure how to alter the readme argument/list entry in the index file.  Does anyone have guidance on what the format for this should look like; i.e., the format of how the entry should look?

Comment: *"Hadley hasn't documented the package that well (staticdocs)"* - the definition of irony?

Comment: It is somewhat ironic, but I think the intial purpose was for use with ggplot2 :-)

Comment: @csgillespie given that I haven't released it, I think you can cut me a break ;)

Comment: @hadley Definitely not a criticism, just an amusing observation (since I suspect it *still* contains better documentation than most other packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Hadley and his team are able to develop staticdocs and its documentation more here is my work around found in a [very rough package](https://github.com/trinker/acc.roxygen2):

```
#' Change read.me File
#'
#' Alter the read.me file with a preset.
#' 
#' @param path Path to the index.html file.
#' @param readme Path to the readme file.
#' @param file The path/file name to output.
readme_statdoc <- function(path, readme, file = NULL) {
    if (length(path) > 1) {
        x <- path
    } else {
        x <- suppressWarnings(readLines(path))
    }
    y <- suppressWarnings(readLines(readme))
    start <- which(grepl("<h1></h1>", x))
    end <- which(grepl("<h2>Help topics</h2>", x))
    x <- c(x[1:start], "", y, "", x[end:length(x)])
    if (!is.null(file)) {
        cat(paste(x, collapse="\n"), file = file)
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Basically you create an external document to insert into the read me portion.  I used this in qdap and you can see how I use it in creating a [staticdoc web site](http://trinker.github.com/qdap/) via [this script](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/inst/maintenance.R).